# Facebook Graph API tag friend(s) while post message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want post some message and tag friends like facebook (web version) does. For example, "simple message @SomeUser". So the question is: how can i tag friends and what is the easiest way to do that?

As i understand there are two ways to do that:

1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed#pubfields but i don't understand why should i provide place id in order to tag friends and where to get (or generate ???) it. Moreover i don't understand where should i get user id. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends? I don't know because request always fails.

2)https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.1#mentions ? I've tried @[userTaggingToken] and replaced userTaggingToken with user id from  /user/taggable_friends. But it doesn't work too. Moreover, user id from /user/taggable_friends is much longer than one provided by example.

I abstract from any sdk so please don't refer to any programming language (and its SDK). Any links to documentation and examples with concrete requests (like .../v2.1/user/feed) and data should be passed (message="...") are welcome.

Comment: 1) is the wrong address in any case, as you are only supposed to use that to tag people that have physically been at a location together with the user. And 2) is not for normal status/message posts, but for Open Graph stories only – so you will have to set up one of these before you can use this.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks! maybe you know some way to just tag message with some user? Is it possible without doing any unnecessary work like making so called "story"? I've read a lot of documentation, but i still have not found any working way to do that.

Comment: No, tagging people in posts made via API is not possible (apart from post with a place, as the first link describes.)